# Which is the first day of the week?

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english

As there is some confusion between Sunday and Monday.
Kindly tell me how to explain when someone ask me this question, that which is the first day of week ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which word(s) can be used instead of "the first day of the week?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16270/which-words-can-be-used-instead-of-the-first-day-of-the-week)

Comment: Just tell them what you said above - ***there is some confusion between Sunday and Monday***. But having worked on scheduling software for various companies in various industries over the years, I should warn you that at least *some* organisations like to start the week on ***Saturday***, which you didn't mention.

Comment: Whichever day you want it to be. Most people would argue that the first day of the year is 1st January - one wouldn't have thought there was much argument about that. But Her Majesty's Revenue Commissioners deem the first day to be 6th April.

Comment: Please include the context of which "week" is meant.  Just like how a day can start anytime based on where you are in the world and how your government has decided on a time zone, a week is seven days and can start anytime according to the government.  Similarly, a person can state "I started my day with coffee..." even though according to the time of day they started it with sleeping.  In what context are you asking the question?

Comment: @WS2 Didn't they get [the memo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_(New_Style)_Act_1750)?

Comment: It's whatever your culture says it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about calendar definitions, which are dependent on locale and culture rather than language.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the English language. Just answer "The first day of the week is" followed by the name of the day. Which day that is is not part of the language, it's part of culture and custom.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of confusion here, and a dozen theories.

One of those points out that the Bible has Jesus rising on the ***first day of the week*** (i.e. Easter Sunday), which is in keeping with the Old Testament tradition (God spent six days creating the world, and rested on the seventh day, Sabbath, known today as Saturday).

Another one suggests that over in England, the Puritans were in favor of "returning" to some of the more austere Old Testament customs, stressing the importance of *works* (in the biblical sense) and the letter of the Mosaic Law (rather than the spirit of said Law, as both Jesus and St. Paul recommended). This necessitated designating Saturday as ***the last (seventh) day of the week***, the day of rest. The sentiment was then exported to the New World by folks who found some of the Puritan ideas congenial to them.

It might be worth noting that in tongues belonging to very different language groups (such as Icelandic (North Germanic), Finnish (Baltic Finnic), and Russian (Slavic), the name for Wednesday means, literally, "middle of the week" (respectively, Keskiviikko, Miðvikudagur, and Среда). One might be tempted to point out that Wednesday is, in fact, the middle of the *work week*; which would not be quite accurate since, in all of the above languages, the name appeared long before the institution of the two day weekend (a very recent development, dating back merely to the beginning of the 20th Century).

Answer (score -2):

ISO-8601 clearly decree that Monday is the fist day of the week, which should end all doubt.

https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/monday.html

Monday is the first day in the whole world. ISO standard clearly says so.. The fact that some countries CONSIDER Sunday or Saturday the first day, doesn't alter the fact that Monday is the first day by decree from ISO!

Comment: There is no doubt that Sunday is the first day of week in the United States, Canada, Australia and other countries. Just as there is no doubt that Saturday is the first day of week in many Arab countries. Have you ever heard of pounds, inches and gallons? According to ISO they don't exist either.

Comment: In that same link it states that "Monday is the first day of the week according to the international standard ISO 8601, but in the US, Canada, and Japan it's counted as the second day of the week."  I'm not sure that the way you worded your answer takes that into consideration.

Comment: Monday is the first day in the whole world. ISO standard clearly says so.. The fact that some countries CONSIDER Sunday or Saturday the first day, doesn't alter the fact that Monday is the first day by decree from ISO!

Comment: @FuxieDK I think you need to read up a little on international law.

Comment: The International Organization for Standardization (ISO) does not legislate at all. It only creates standards that have nothing to do with legal issues.